# Find the energy spectrum of a function

Tags: signal-processing

We have been given x(t) and h(t) with their functions and we are required to compute the energy spectra of y $S_y(f)=S_X(f)|H(f)|^2$
Where $S_y$ is the energy spectrum of $y(t)$ and $S_x$ is the energy spectrum of $x(t)$

I have found $S_x(f)$ and $H(f)=\frac {2a} {a^2 +r\pi^2f^2}$ with a being a generic number in $R>0$ .

What im a bit confused about is. When it asks for $|H(f)^2|$  is it asking for the literal function $H(f)=\frac {2a} {a^2 +r\pi^2f^2}$ squared,  or do i have to find the energy of
$|H(f)|$?

I dont need computations, i just need a bit of clarification on this part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have signal $x(t)$ and filter $h(t)$ with respective Fourier transforms $X(\omega)$ and $H(\omega)$, then the filtered signal $y(t)$ is obtained by
$$
y(t)=(x \ast h)(t) \Longleftrightarrow Y(\omega)=X(\omega)H(\omega).
$$
If you want the energy spectrum, or PSD, you take absolute values and square in order to get from '*complex amplitude*' to '*energy*':
$$
|Y(\omega)|^2=|X(\omega)|^2|H(\omega)|^2,
$$
which is a result of $Y(\omega)Y^\ast(\omega)=|Y(\omega)|^2$.

You can write the result a bit differently as
$$
S_y(\omega)=S_x(\omega)|H(\omega)|^2.
$$
The phrase '*take absolute values and square*' is no more and no less what to do. So if your $H(\omega)$ is positive and real valued and therefore $H(\omega)=|H(\omega)|$ (which seems to apply to your case), then you can just take the square of it.

Your $H(\omega)$ has the same form as $|H(\omega)|^2$ of a first order lowpass filter. Check your results.